# WinForms HTML visualizing controls comparison

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on some project which requires some HTML visualizing control (WinForms).
Currently I am aware only of two such a controls:
AxWebBrowser (as far as I understand this is IE-based ActiveX control for winforms)
Nabu HTMLView (open source library with visualizing capabilities).

Are there any other choices? What are their cons and pros?
How configurable they are? For example I want to disable navigation and scripts, hook onto loading methods to override resources loading and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with trying to fin a suitable control for editing HTML in a winforms app.

After evaluating half a dozen or so, I settled on PinEdit http://www.pintexx.com/

Comment: Does PinEdit support "view only" mode? Or it allows to edit HTML without any other options?

Comment: Yes. You can control what controls are available, and can set to control you readonly mode. Best thing to do is download the trial and see if it meets your needs.  Worked for what I needed.

Comment: The url is not valid anymore?